i'm trying to do a login with springboot and JWT and i got this problem
this is the entire code (the importations are the indicated for the code)
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration,
                                                AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authManager) throws Exception {
        JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter();
        jwtAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        jwtAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/v1/login");
        JWTAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter = new JWTAuthorizationFilter();

        return http
                .formLogin(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer::permitAll)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/users/byEmail/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/products").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*");
                registry.addMapping("/media/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200")); // Allow localhost:4200
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer1() {
        return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/media/{filname:.+}"));
    }
}

I try doing again the code, looking the other classes and looking in internet and i got no idea of what or why is the problem. When i compile the code i got this:

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/poli/redsolidaria/Config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChain' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [com/poli/redsolidaria/Config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Factory method 'authenticationManager' threw exception with message: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@37aea657 to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:875) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:828) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.poli.redsolidaria.RedSolidariaApplication.main(RedSolidariaApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/poli/redsolidaria/Config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChain' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [com/poli/redsolidaria/Config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Factory method 'authenticationManager' threw exception with message: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@37aea657 to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:545) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1488) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:867) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [com/poli/redsolidaria/Config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Factory method 'authenticationManager' threw exception with message: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@37aea657 to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:654) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:642) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Factory method 'authenticationManager' threw exception with message: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@37aea657 to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@37aea657 to already built object
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.add(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:182) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.apply(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:125) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder.apply(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.java:280) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.java:182) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$DefaultPasswordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:298) ~[spring-security-config-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at com.poli.redsolidaria.Config.WebSecurityConfig.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfig.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.poli.redsolidaria.Config.WebSecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$authenticationManager$3(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.poli.redsolidaria.Config.WebSecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at com.poli.redsolidaria.Config.WebSecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.authenticationManager(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 51 common frames omitted

is the first time that i work with Springboot and is so difficult. I dont know nothing about this kind of problem

can you add definition of this class - DaoAuthenticationConfigurer
